# ssl.SSLError: ('No cipher can be selected') When Trying to Set TLS1.3 Cipher Suites in Python SSL

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl, tls1.3, ccm

I am having a problem when trying to set TLS1.3 ciphers for ssl contexts in python, particularly 'TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256'.

OS: Windows 7

Python version: 3.7.4

OpenSSL version: 1.1.1c

By default, when i'm not setting cipher suites, it can be seen in the TLS handshake that the client does offer some TLS1.3 ciphers, but not the ones I need.

```py
import ssl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    ctx.set_ciphers('TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256')
    print(ctx.get_ciphers())
```

The error I receive:

ssl.SSLError:('No cipher can be selected.',)

Comment: You will have to select a set of ciphers that has at least one item in common with what the clients supports. Also I notices that it is called set_cipher**s**. If a sequence is expected, the string might be interpreted as a sequence of single characters. Try to put a comma before the `)`.

Comment: 1. The client supports these ciphers, but I'm not trying to establish a handshake yet. First I try to set the cipher suite.

2. The set_ciphers function supports single cipher suites. It works with other ciphers. Also the syntax for this is set_ciphers('cipherSuite_A:cipherSuite_B:...')

Comment: Did you manage to establish a handshake with this TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 ?am i facing same issue , I want to use PSK-NULL-SHA256 but could not see in the cipher suite list

Answer (score 0):

This is because set_ciphers does not apply to TLSv1.3, so you can't enable nor disable those cipher suite (In your example "TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256" is one of them.)

source = https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_ciphers